# In Fortran, does slicing an array create a copy in memory?

Tags: fortran, slice, fortran90

Say I pass a slice of an array into a subroutine that manipulates its inputs:

```
some_subroutine(a(:,1))
```

Is that section of the original `a` altered, or is some copy of `a(:,1)` altered?

Comment: For gfortran, the option "-Warray-temporaries" or "-fcheck-array-temporaries" is useful to get some info about temporaries. Also, you can print the address of the first element of actual and dummy arrays somehow to check if they point to the same memory (e.g., with c_loc() or loc()) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of other answers, which perhaps address slightly different (but relevant) points.  Here I'll attempt to reconcile them.

[Vladimir F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40957716) looks at the so-called copy-in/copy-out mechanism; [bfletch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40956608) the final effect on the argument.

In general, the effect of the following

```
integer i(2,2)
i=0
call dosomething(i(1,:))   ! Just to make it not contiguous.

contains
  subroutine dosomething(j)
    integer j(2)  ! or j(*), or j(:)
    j=1
  end subroutine
end program
```

is that the array `i` has some elements set to `1` and the others `0`.  So, yes: regardless of whether there is a temporary copy (as from one answer) what can be observed after the call is that it's the actual argument itself that is modified.

Naturally, there is an exception: the `value` attribute.<sup>1</sup> If the subroutine above is instead like

```
subroutine doseomthing(j)
  integer, value :: j(2)
  j=1
end subroutine
```

then there is indeed a true copy of the argument.  Modifications to the dummy argument `j` are not reflected in the actual argument the section of `i`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is for current Fortran.  Fortran 90, as tagged, hasn't this feature.

Comment: Now it seems to me you probably read the actual intention of the OP better. The problem is that the title is "does it create a copy in memory" but then the final question is whether the original is modified.

Comment: I've only just noticed that this is a self-answered question, but even with that context it's certainly valuable to say about temporary copies.  Possibly I could also add: there's nothing about the slicing that creates a copy and here we're looking only at the case of a slice being an argument.  Array slice assignments may also require temporary copies.

Answer (score 4):

That depends if `a` is itself contiguous and how does `some_subroutine` look like.

You probably silently assume `a` is contiguous, but it doesn't have to be if `a` is itself some slice passed as an assumed-shape array or an array pointer.

Even if `a` is not contiguous and hence `a(:,1)` also isn't, a copy will not be needed if `some_subroutine` accepts an assumed shape argument

```
subroutine some_sub(b)
  real :: some_sub(:)
```